# Merging multiple List<CustomType> when grouping in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have this models:

```
public class AudienceInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Departments { get; set; }
    public List<CountOfDestination> CountOfDestinations { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CountOfDestination
{
    public string DestinationName { get; set; }
    public int? CountRoom { get; set; }
    public int? CountOfFiles { get; set; }
}
```

And this table in DB.

```
public class AudienceInfo : IModelWithId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ....

    public RoomPurpose RoomPurpose { get; set; }

    public List<AudienceInfo_File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

After selecting the "Departments" (where condition), I get a list of data. Then, I GroupBy "RoomPurpose" and get 
"CountRoom" for every row = DestinationName. This part work correctly. 
Also, i need to get the CountOfFiles ... don't know how to do this

```
   return dbAudInfo
               .Where(x => x.RightOfPreferentialUse.Id == Id)
               .Select(x => new AudienceInfo
               {
                   Departments = x.RightOfPreferentialUse.Name,
                   Date = date1,
                   CountOfDestinations = dbAudInfo
                        .GroupBy(z => new { z.RoomPurpose })
                        .Select(y => new CountOfDestination
                        {
                            DestinationName = y.Key.RoomPurpose.Name,
                            CountRoom = y.Count(z => z.RightOfPreferentialUse.Id == Id),
                            CountOfFiles = ?????????????????????????
                        }).ToList()
               }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

How can i connect a list in LINQ query with GroupBy.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, i need to get the CountOfFiles ... don't know how to do this

Use:

```
CountOfFiles = y.ToList().First(a => a.Id == y.Id).Files.Count()
```

> How can i connect a list in LINQ query with GroupBy.

Can you elaborate?